# Given the typical pace of Parliament, what is roughly the earliest one could see the renters reform bill becoming law?

Tags: united-kingdom

How long does it take for such a Bill to make it through Parliament and gain parliamentary assent?

Comment: Somewhere between two sitting days (e.g. the Early Parliamentary General Election Act 2019) and never is all that anyone can tell you. It depends on a whole host of things.

Comment: A question about the minumum and regular time it usually takes from a political idea to a law is an interesting and useful question. But I think it would fare better without linking the question to a particular subject matter. The content of the bill doesn't matter for answering this question and it makes it look like a push question to promote a political cause.

Comment: @Philipp While I broadly agree with your comment, the content of the bill _does_ matter. An uncontroversial bill will likely go through its stages - especially the Committee (line-by-line scrutiny) stage - much faster in each House than a bill that has a lot of opposition. More prosaically, a long and complex bill is likely to take longer than a short and simple one. This is one is hard to predict, because although Labour are likely to support a lot of the ideas in it, I'd imagine there may be opposition from landlord MPs.

Comment: I feel this is too speculative because it asks for a specific project. Nobody knows for that. It should only ask in general. Then the distribution would be very broad and not very informative but at least answerable.

Answer (score 3):

It's impossible to answer this, as ultimately it's up to the Government, and affected by the level of opposition in each House.

There must be an election by January 2025, though the latest rumours suggest a date of [autumn 2024](https://www.londonworld.com/read-this/prime-minister-rishi-sunak-hints-at-autumn-2024-for-next-general-election-how-long-is-a-parliamentary-term-4098825), so obviously any legislation must complete its passage through Parliament before then.

Comment: In fact Parliament will likely be prorogued in the autumn of 2023 and a new session opened,  If it hasn't completed all stages by then, it would have to be re-introduced, as a new bill.

Comment: @JamesK Specifically, it's likely to be [carried over](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/carrying-over-bills/carrying-over-bills-in-parliament) to the new session, as has already happened with one or two bills that are unlikely to be completed in this session.